# telnet login using batch

Tags: batch-file, authentication, telnet

I have created a bat file which open telnet session.
Problem is I couldn't send any keys for username {Enter} ; Password{Enter}
I have tried so many things from similar blogs, unfortunately dint work for me so far.

I tried download expect.
Printf for user name password.
echo for user name password.
telnet -l ftpcmd.dat:teftpcmd.dat %servername% | -m 
telnet -l ftpcmd.dat:teftpcmd.dat %servername% | -f file name
( "echo username"; sleep 2; echo "password") | telnet -l 10.89.193.2
[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: Windows JAVA   ...........................................

Comment: here is another attempt;

Comment: rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

SET servername=10.89.193.2

echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat

telnet -l :ftpcmd.dat %servername%

del ftpcmd.dat
del telnetcmd.dat
 
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "904050"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
 
%SendKeys% "720506"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}

goto :EOF
@end

// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));

Comment: just edit your question instead of putting all that code in a comment.

Comment: What you need is a scriptable telnet client.  Google search for **Telnet Scripting Tool Albert Yale**.